# Google Data Studio Scrolling up and down is not working in the present mode

Tags: google-data-studio

I have used Google Data Studio for years now, and lately, I've noticed that when am presenting with the Actual Width option, I can't scroll down to see the rest of the page.

I have a lot of reports built this way, and I am so frustrated I can't find the issue, I have tried using different devices, and different browsers, but it's still happening.

Please help me,

Example: https://lookerstudio.google.com/s/s5a4aDmAe3A

Steps to get to the issue:

Step 1: click the 3 dots on the right of the Edit button
Step 2: click present
step 3: Using the list on the down-left corner of the page, choose 'Display Option' then choose 'fit to width'

and now you are stuck, you can't scroll down

Comment: @Blindspots ♦  I just did what you asked me, can you please check the issue

Comment: Thank you for doing that.  I'm looking into it.

Comment: FYI did some digging but didn't  complete yet. Have confirmed the issue as you described and also that it seems at odds with expected behavior. You mentioned *"lately"* but can I get you to explicitly confirm that this behavior was different before and if so when did it change?

Comment: @Blindspots that is true, it used to scroll down normally, it changed a couple of weeks ago, and I've tried different browsers and devices, but still not working.